# Open Mobile Safari from a Link in a WebView

Tags: ios, webview

Is there a URI scheme to open Mobile Safari to a specific URL?

e.g.,

```
<a href="safari://open_url/?url=google.com">Open Google in Safari</a>
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a way to do this?

Comment: I am looking for this as well.

Comment: Di you find a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: 
So, as of iOS 6.0.2, there is still isn't a URL scheme specific to MobileSafari (see below). However, Federico Viticci has posted an [interesting hack](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/chrome-for-ios-send-a-webpage-back-to-safari-via-bookmarklet/) that will allow you to call Safari from Chrome for iOS. It's not as functional as a Chrome-to-Safari bookmarklet, but it does show it's possible to launch MobileSafari from Chrome for iOS.

**Original Answer**:
It turns out you can't open a link in Safari using just a URI scheme. Hyperlinks in other apps can be opened in safari using `openURL` (see other answers), but there is no scheme for MobileSafari itself (which you would need if you were to open a link in Safari using a hyperlink in Chrome or Opera for iOS).

Google Chrome has the following two URI schemes: `googlechrome://` and `googlechromes://` (for HTTPS) that work just as any other app-specific scheme (such as `dayone://`, `things://`, or `sms://`).

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I understand what you are asking for.

Have a class implement the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.  Implement the method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This method gets called whenever the user clicks a link in your webview.  You can get the URL the user clicked on be inspecting the `request` parameter.  You can then intercept any links you want to open in mobile Safari rather then inside your webView and then call `-openURL:` on the shared application as in my other answer.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URLFromRequest];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
```

Comment: I need the link to be in HTML, not client app code. Updating the question to be more clear - sorry Simon!

Comment: I think Kirk is looking for a specific URL scheme (akin to the URL scheme used to open preferences before 5.1: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];`).

Comment: @Kirk I just edited my answer, if you open a URL with the HTTP scheme, it will use mobile safari.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.replace("x-web-search://?your search here");
```

URI Scheme for safari is- **x-web-search://**

This will open your search in safari browser.

Comment: do you know if this works on current versions of iOS (e.g., 12.4 ?) I see `x-web-search` suggested across the web but I suspect this scheme might be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the webkit javascript bridge https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

This allows you to send messages from javascript to xcode.
I use this to close the webview from the html page:

```
self.bridge = [WebViewJavascriptBridge bridgeForWebView:self.webView handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback) {
            NSLog(@"Received message from javascript: %@", data);
            if ([data isEqual:@"closewin!"])
                [self dismissModal];
        }];
```

but you could also use this to jump to safari or anything you want