# How to open browser from html in objective c

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode

So i have HTML that is loaded into web view and inside that html i have link like that

```
a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">google</a>
```

So have do i make that link open inside a default browser not inside my web view .

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
       if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
          return NO;
       }
       return YES;
 }
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452719/how-do-i-open-links-in-safari-instead-of-uiwebview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390479/open-mobile-safari-from-a-link-in-a-webview).

Comment: well i have html oppened and from that html i open new link so that's not what i'm looking for

Comment: OK i finaly understand what u did Thank u!