# Open UIWebView Link in Safari without changing objective-c code (only javascript)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, safari

I have a UIWebview and I want to open a link in Safari browser (in order to fix some other bug). The problem is that my app is SDK code attached to a hosting native application (it integrates our SDK). I cannot change my objective-c code for now (have to find javascript code only solution without sending another SDK version of native code to my client).
I tried window.open(url, '_blank') but it did not do the job. Is there a way to make this happening? Please do not give me an Objective-c answers. As I wrote, the solution I seek for now is javascript only.
tnx!

Comment: Don't think so. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390479/open-mobile-safari-from-a-link-in-a-webview