# How to force UIWebView to open link in browser?

Tags: html, ios, url-scheme

We have a site. In some cases users can open in from Facebook App or VKontakte App using built-in browser. And there is a link which I want to open in Safari or another browser. But not in this WebView.

Is any HTML property or something that can tell the WebView not top open this link in itself?

UPDATE: I am not a App developer. I am web developer. And I do not have any access to Facebook App. I need to force Facebook App to open links not in its built-in browser.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to add target="_blank" to the link, but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: No that will not do anything with `UIWebView` have you tried any of the answers given? You need to be intercepting the click in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` and return NO so the `UIWebView` will not load but before returning NO you will need to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: I can't try answers below, because I can only modify the website.

Comment: Sorry but you have tagged your question incorrectly then. If this is site related only and you aren't developing the app itself so no objective-c what does this have to do with `UIWebViews`? Please retag your question correctly.

Comment: I have retagged this question to html as this doesn't have anything to do with `UIWebViews`

Comment: See the Update to my answer what you are looking for are called URL Schemes.

Comment: Unfortunately URL Schemes is not a solution, all http & https scheme will open in Safari by default, there are no custom url scheme for Safari app.

Answer (score 4):

You can use UIWebViewDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if(UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType /*you can add some checking whether link should be opened in Safari */) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web view contains some delegate methods to find the click event from that delegate method you need to call the URL like this

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
```

This is the delegate method which will fire while clicking any link inside the web view

```
    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
}

}
```

just differentiate the URL with the URLRequest .

Comment: You have a typo in `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[request URL]];`

Comment: Different typo now it should be `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];`

Comment: Fixed now I can give +1.

Answer (score -1):

If you have set the `UIWebViewDelegate` you can use the method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Using this method we can block or allow certain links/urls to be opened in either the `UIWebView` or in the mobile browser.

So we can do something like

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    // We only want to block links
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];
        if([url isEqualToString:@"http://www.google.co.uk"]) {
            // If the requested url is a link and is http://www.google.co.uk block it from loading in the UIWebView and load it in the mobile browser.
            if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenUrl:[request URL]]) {
                // We should be checking to make sure we can open it first, for whatever reason we might not be able to and we don't want to give the user a bad journey.
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];

                // We also need to tell our UIWebView not to do anything so we need to return NO.
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    // If all is OK and we are happy for any other link to be included then just return YES and continue.
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to block all links then just remove the `isEqualToString:` `if statement` or you can just block certain links by adding `else if` to the `if statement`. This code does one of two things it will either load the clicked link site in the `UIWebView` or it will load the site in the mobile browser if it passes the `if statements`.

**UPDATE**

It turns out the user isn't doing the `objective-c` side of things they are doing the `html` which wasn't in the original question, but since this could help users in the future I will leave my answer here.

**EDIT**

Since the user is using `html` to try and direct the user to the mobile browser what they are looking for is called URL Schemes. Unfortunately I don't believe there is any URL Scheme as of `iOS 7` that will open safari mobile browser.
This question has been asked before so I am not going to sit here and saying everything again I will just direct you to the question and answer [Open Mobile Safari from a Link in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390479/open-mobile-safari-from-a-link-in-a-webview)

Answer (score -1):

```
//codigo para abrir no safari
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {

NSURL *requestURL =[ [ request URL ] retain ];
if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @”http” ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @”https” ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @”mailto” ])&& ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) )
{ return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ]; } [     requestURL release ]; return YES;

}
```