# Open URL in phone's web browser instead of 3'rd party app's webview

Tags: ios, google-oauth

We developed a website in which users can sign in using their google account. This works fine. A lot of people have shared our app link on Instagram.

The problem is, when users of Instagram click on our website link, the ios webview is used (internal browser in Instagram). This prevents people from signing in to our app and are presented the following error:

[image]

What's the solution to this?

Comment: have a look
"Open Mobile Safari from a Link in a WebView" https://stackoverflow.com/a/12719012/6303078

Comment: I am not sure there is any way for you to detect that the user is coming from a webview and then force them over to a real browser.   I think thats going to require access to the orignal application running the web view.